# How to convert Dword to Qword

Tags: python

I want to convert Qword to Dword. By Programmer calculator, I easily convert it but not found any way in python.

```
Qword = 562949953442333
Dword = 21021
```

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF & 562949953442333`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bit-wise AND operator to mask the Qword with `0xffff`:

```
print(562949953442333 & 0xffff)
```

This outputs:

```
21021
```

Comment: How we did the same thing in SQL?